# Two HTML input type submits crashes form when opening in Windows App and Xamarin Windows

Tags: html, windows

```
<div class="positive">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
</div>
```

This is causing my form to crash when opening in a Windows App and when using Xamarin in Windows. When I change it to type button it works which is fine. But why? I've seen this used before many times and never had an issue until now.

Just curious if anyone know the specifics as to why this happens?

Comment: NOTE: I use the very same code in other forms on other devices and platforms and it works fine.

Comment: I actually figured this out. There is special javascript handling in a save event listener. The listener was missing e.preventDefault(); hence allowing the native browser behavior before reaching the windows code. And since the app was auto-saving, it appeared as though the form was crashing in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out. There is special javascript handling in a save event listener. The listener was missing e.preventDefault(); hence allowing the native browser behavior before reaching the windows code. And since the app was auto-saving, it appeared as though the form was crashing in the app. –